# Receive TCP stream with socketTextStream from external server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, pyspark, spark-streaming

Is it possible to receive from a Spark streaming application running in a local SparkContext data from an external TCP server using socketTextStream? E.g,

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext("local[2]", "app")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 0.5)
socketDstream = ssc.socketTextStream("XXX.XXXXXX.com", 30000)
```

It is working correctly using a standard socket,

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("XXX.XXXXXX.com", 30000))
data = recvall(s)
```

But it doesn't work in Spark.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Just calling `socketDstream.pprint()` - all the Dstreams are empty. Furthermore, taking a look into the UI at `localhost:4041/streaming/`, the average received records is always 0 for _SocketReceiver-0_.